# How to speed up plt.savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am calling plt.savefig like this:

```
plt.savefig( 'c:/temp/figure.png', dpi=200 )
```

It takes about 0.6 seconds to run. And I am saving lots of charts.

I run my scripts in interactive mode, and so can't use multiprocessing.

Is there a way I can speed up the savefig function? Can I make it non-blocking?

Comment: Why do you run in interactive mode? Matplotlib is certainly not the fasted plotting library, but if you avoid using a window backend and use multiprocessing it is usually fast enough.

Comment: The bottle neck in actually the text rendering.